# error with push nuget package to azure devops artifact repository

Tags: azure-devops, nuget, nuget-package, azure-artifacts, nuget-spec

I have a ClassLibrary App and i want to create nuget package from it  and push to my azure devops artifact repository
Now
I am create nuspec file for my project from "nuget.exe spec myApp.csproj' and create package with "nuget.exe pack" , now when i pushing package to my azure devops artifact with this command 
nuget.exe push -Source "public" -ApiKey ****************************  Asa.Infra.Pusher.Proxy.1.1.9.nupkg
returned error for me and the package not pushed to the repository
the error log is:

Response status code does not indicate success: 500 (Internal Server Error - Failed to retrieve data from the upstream package source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': An error occurred while sending the request. (DevOps Activity ID: 0CEBC8A7-EBE4-40F1-887A-7055A75D9227)).

I must say :
my ApiKey is ok and has full permission
and I've pushed a package to this repository in the past but now I have problem with it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find a problem
My Azure Devops Server haven't access to https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
grant access and resolve my problem

Comment: Great! Thanks for sharing your solution here, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/) , so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.